# How to trigger click event if selector is loaded from external

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do anyone has similar experience? I would like to load an external file into current page by using .load("...") function. After loading, how can I trigger the click on an image in the <div id="tab-3-list">?

The script

```
$("#tab-3-list img.coupon_list").on("click", function (e) {}
```

doesn't function. If I embed the content of list.html into the current body, the above script works.

```
<html lang="en" class="ui-mobile">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">

</head>
<section id="home" data-role="page">
    <article data-role="content">
        <div id="home-content"></div>
    </article>
    <!-- content -->
</section>
<!-- home -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#home-content").load("list.html");
        $("#tab-3-list img.coupon_list").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.alert(this.id);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

External file list.html

```
    <div id="tab-3-list">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <img id="c01" class="coupon_list" src="/images/coupon/c01.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ui-grid-a -->
    </div>
    <!-- /tab-3-list -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) at this context since you are loading the DOM elements at runtime,

```
$("#home-content").on("click","#tab-3-list img.coupon_list",function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#home-content").load("list.html", function(){
 $("#tab-3-list img.coupon_list").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.alert(this.id);
        });
});

    });
</script>
```

Comment: yep... but home-content load event is written on DOM ready event.. so definitly binds one  time on dom ready..

Answer (score 0):

`load` uses ajax and thus takes sometime to load data from external page. When you are attaching `click` `event` to `img.coupon_list`, it's not even present in DOM ( in page ).

Try this,

```
$("#home-content").load("list.html", function () {
        $("#tab-3-list img.coupon_list").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.alert(this.id);
        });
});
```

This is attaching `click` only when data from `load` is returned and added to the DOM.

Comment: And what if, in future OP has changed his code to call that loading function to be happened via a button click in order to make that page dynamic..?

Comment: That is redundant, what if OP decides to shut down this project ? :D. We can always `off` the `click` before using on `on` it. That said, your answer is perfectly valid one :) +1 on that

Comment: @Jashwant haha... :) Basically I would like to use/suggest a permanent/concrete solution to this kind of problems. That's why I just insisted the same to you..

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation - **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)**, and to trigger click event use **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#home-content").load("list.html",
        function(){ 
           $('#tab-3-list img.coupon_list').trigger('click');
    });
    $("#home-content").on("click","#tab-3-list img.coupon_list", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: as a sidenote, you should try to avoid using `on` on `document`. This is reason why `live` was deprecated.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `#home-content` is specific  to this question. So , to get it generic added document. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
-just put event in live mode , it's work after reload :

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#home-content").load("list.html");

            $("#home-content").one("load",function(){
           //  everytime an image finishes loading    
       }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) {

         // manually trigger load event in
        // event of a cache pull
         $(this).trigger("click");
        }
      });          

       $("#home-content #tab-3-list img.coupon_list").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.alert(this.id);
        });
    }); </script>
```

Comment: Please, follow new one

Comment: I use both jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js but .live() is not defined, in what version of jquery and jquery.mobile require to have .live() function?

Comment: Please,use latest version of jquery from site.